# How to use fopen() in php?

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to make my code able to log any kind of errors on opening a database. What i am trying to do is , create a .txt file that all the logs will be saved in there in case of error.

What i ve done so far is :

```
bla bla bla
} catch(PDOException $e) {
        //in case of error , we create a log file with the error
        //$PDOException_file = 'PDOException_file_' . date('Y_m_d-H-i-s') . '.txt' ;
        $PDOException_file =  'PDOException_file' . '.txt' ;
        $fh = fopen($PDOException_file, 'w') or die();
        fwrite($fh, date('Y_m_d-H-i-s') . ' PDOException Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n" );
        fclose($fh);
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }
```

What i expected from the code i wrote would be to create one .txt file "PDOException" file and inside get the logs like this :

```
2013_05_02-12-40-02 PDOException Error: bla bla bla


2013_05_02-12-43-02 PDOException Error: bla bla bla 


2013_05_02-13-45-02 PDOException Error: bla bla bla
```

That means every time i have an error , open the file , write the error make 2 new lines close the file. Then the next time i get an error , i write to the end of this file the error etc etc.

What happens though is that i rewrite in the beginning of my file on the old data. How can i avoid that?

Comment: Pay heed to the value of the second argument passed to fopen(), and read the friendly documentation

Comment: Use a or a+ instead of w+ in the fopen handle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code where you have:

```
$fh = fopen($PDOException_file, 'w') or die()
```

You should use:

```
$fh = fopen($PDOException_file, 'a') or die()
```

The `w` open's the file for writing only and places the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length (deleting all contents). If the file does not exist, it will attempt to create it. The `a` will open the file for writing only and place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist it will attempt to create it.

You can find more information on `fopen()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: In notepad , it doesnt show me the result with the newline. In notepad++ though it does. Is this expected behavior or am i doing smth wrong?

Comment: @DonP - it's the difference between "\n" and "\r\n" for newlines - learn to live with the foibles and differences between *nux/Windoze/Mac

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead with **FILE_APPEND** flag as an alternative method:

```
file_put_contents($PDOException_file, date('Y_m_d-H-i-s') . ' PDOException Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
Has alot of examples, and information on how to use it.

What you want to do tho, is replace the 'w' with an 'a'.
This places the pointer at the end of the file, rather than the beginning, this way you will not overwrite any existing text in the file.

Comment: Chill.. just trying to help. Update your page, accidently submitted it before writing the rest...

Comment: @DonP What's your complain? His second sentence answers you.

Comment: @Barmar , he edited the answer thats why you can see that now. Sorry man , but it was frustrating getting as an answer to read the manual. Of course now its really helpful what you are saying , as you specifically answered my question.

Comment: I saw his edit a couple minutes before you complained. And there were also several other good answers posted a few seconds after him, so how frustrating could it be. People often update their answers incrementally, you should allow a few minutes for things to settle down before jumping down someone's throat.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your file has already existed or not.

the fopen parameter you are using is 'w' which will create a new file and replace your old file. You can use 'a' to append your file.

this 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php
and this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
might be a proper references

Comment: Why does he need to check whether it exists?

Comment: My answer is to accommodate those who want to create the file if it does not exist and if it exists, they just read the content, remanipulate it, and write a new file using w parameter.

Comment: Opening with `a` mode will create it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mode in which fopen opens a file. You have used the mode "W" ie it will open the file in write mode with pointer at the begin thats why every time your file data removed and you paste data from very begin. So instead of that use "a" which open the file in append mode that means your existing data will remain there and new data will be appended after that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
    $myFile="text.txt";
    $original_data=file_get_contents($myFile);
    $new_data=original_data."\n\n".'PDOException Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents($myFile,$new_data);
```